# Не получается запустить исходник delphi

Tags: delphi

Нашел код программы, нужно скомпилировать и запустить. Делаю в RAD Studio 10.2
Создаю новый юнит, вставляю код. Выдает ошибки по кнопкам формам и т.д.

```
unit Unit1;

interface
uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Memo3: TMemo;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);

private
    { Private declarations }

public
    { Public declarations }

end;
var
    Form1: TForm1;
    // Alfabet:array [0..255] of char;
    str:string;
    newstr:string ;
    a,c,t,m:integer;
implementation
{$R *.DFM}

function testingcount(s:string):boolean;
    var SetCount: set of char;
    i:integer;
    begin
        TRIM(S);
        IF s=” then
            begin
                testingcount:=false;
                exit;
            end;
        SetCount := [‘1’, ‘2’,’3′,’4′,’5′,’6′,’7′,’8′,’9′,’0′];
        testingcount:=true;
        if length(s)>1 then
            if (not(s[1] in SetCount) and (not(s[1]<>’0′))) then // проверка, чтобы число не начиналось с нуля
                begin
                    testingcount:=false;
                    exit;
                end;
        for i:=2 to length(s) do
            if (not(s[i] in SetCount)) then
                begin
                    testingcount:=false;
                    exit;
                end;
    end;

function code(s:char):char; //кодирование и декодирование
    var j,litera:integer;
    begin
        t:=(a*t+c)mod m;
        litera:=t xor ord(s);
        code:=chr(litera);
    end;

procedure read;
    var i:integer;
    begin
        if testingcount(Form1.Edit1.Text) then 
            a:=StrToInt(Form1.Edit1.Text)
        else 
            begin
                ShowMessage(‘Некорректно задан параметр А’);
                exit;
            end;
        if testingcount(Form1.Edit2.Text) then 
            c:=StrToInt(Form1.Edit2.Text)
        else
            begin
                ShowMessage(‘Некорректно задан параметр C’);
                exit;
            end;
        if testingcount(Form1.Edit3.Text) then 
            t:=StrToInt(Form1.Edit3.Text)
        else
            begin
                ShowMessage(‘Некорректно задана порождающая величина’);
                exit;
            end;
    end;

procedure transformation(var s,s1:string);
    var i:integer;
    res:char;
    begin
        s1:=”;
        m:=32;
        for i:=1 to length(s) do
            begin
                if ((ord(s[i])=$A) or (ord(s[i])=$D) ) then
                    s1:=s1+s[i]
                else
                    begin
                        res:=code(s[i]);
                        s1:=s1+res;
                    end;
            end;
    end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var j,litera:integer;
    begin
        read;
        str:=Form1.Memo1.Text;
        transformation(str,newstr);
        Form1.Memo2.Text:=NEWstr;
    end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        Form1.Memo1.Clear;
    end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        Form1.Memo2.Clear;
    end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        Form1.Memo3.Text:=”;
        newstr:=Form1.Memo2.Text;
        read;
        transformation(newstr,str);
        Form1.Memo3.Text:=str;
    end;
end.
```

Comment: Вам строчка `{$R *.DFM}` о чем-нибудь говорит?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 3):

> Создаю новый юнит, вставляю код.

Данный подход хороший для консольных приложений. У Вас модуль для VCL формы. Она состоит из 2-х файлов `<Unit>.pas` и `<Unit>.dfm`. В `<Unit>.pas` хранится код, в `<Unit>.dfm` - разметка.

По факту Вам не достает файла `<Unit>.dfm`. Он может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 373
  ClientWidth = 535
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 8
    Top = 11
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 8
    Top = 43
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label2'
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Left = 8
    Top = 75
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label3'
  end
  object Label4: TLabel
    Left = 313
    Top = 11
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label4'
  end
  object Label5: TLabel
    Left = 313
    Top = 125
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label5'
  end
  object Label6: TLabel
    Left = 313
    Top = 239
    Width = 31
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Label6'
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 72
    Top = 8
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Edit1'
  end
  object Edit2: TEdit
    Left = 72
    Top = 40
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Edit2'
  end
  object Edit3: TEdit
    Left = 72
    Top = 72
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = 'Edit3'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 216
    Top = 17
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 3
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 216
    Top = 49
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Clear memo1'
    TabOrder = 4
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object Button3: TButton
    Left = 216
    Top = 81
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button3'
    TabOrder = 5
    OnClick = Button3Click
  end
  object Button4: TButton
    Left = 216
    Top = 113
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Clear memo2'
    TabOrder = 6
    OnClick = Button4Click
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 313
    Top = 30
    Width = 185
    Height = 89
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo1')
    TabOrder = 7
  end
  object Memo2: TMemo
    Left = 313
    Top = 144
    Width = 185
    Height = 89
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo2')
    TabOrder = 8
  end
  object Memo3: TMemo
    Left = 313
    Top = 258
    Width = 185
    Height = 89
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo3')
    TabOrder = 9
  end
end
```